In LyX, I can't seem to overwrite some shortcut keys
In LyX 2.4, I changed the shortcut for "bookmark-save 1" from "Alt+1" to "Shift+F1".
I also added the shortcut "Alt+1" for "textstyle-update color 16" (changing selected text to red):

But now when I try selecting the text "sdgsdg" (below) and hitting "Alt+1", the command that is executed is still "Save Bookmark" instead of changing the color of the selected text to red:

(The shortcut "Alt+1" for "textstyle-update color 16" worked perfectly well in LyX 2.3.)
What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug with the new LyX 2.4?

Shortcuts defined with M-~S cannot be unbound. It is a known bug, see https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org/msg222077.html
